# Powershell filtering PSCsutomobjects

Tags: powershell

I would like to ask you for help with getting/filtering informations from the array/pscustomobjects.

I have this command:

```
$queryResults = (qwinsta /server:$server | foreach { (($_.trim() -replace "\s+",","))} | ConvertFrom-Csv)
```

which gives me back something like this:

```
SESSIONNAME : rdp-tcp#1
USERNAME    : tnejtek
ID          : 3
STATE       : Active
TYPE        : 
DEVICE      : 

SESSIONNAME : console
USERNAME    : 5
ID          : Conn
STATE       : 
TYPE        : 
DEVICE      : 

SESSIONNAME : rdp-tcp
USERNAME    : 65536
ID          : Listen
STATE       : 
TYPE        : 
DEVICE      :
```

Now I would like to be able to set the conditions with if statement based on the connected user and its session state. For example, if username is tnejtek and state is active then write "tnejtek is connected", if the username would be "xxx" and session state would be disconnected, write "user xxx is disconnected"

Currently I tried this

```
   if 
   (($queryResults -match "tnejtek") -and ($queryResults -match "Active")) {
  
   write-host "tnejtek is connected"
   }
   else {
   "user not found"
   }
```

but this is not working, because I am able to check that in variable $queryResults  is user tnejtek, but I dont know how to check directly if his user state is active or not, in the example I am checking that tnejtek is there and that some session has state active.

Thank you very much

Comment: `Where-Object` is a cmdlet made for this. It filters items that are streamed down the pipeline: `Get-Service | Where-Object -Property Name -match "notepad"`. These also aren't `PSCustomObjects`, they're *service* objects.

Comment: Please try to not change your question completely. As for your new/updated question, you can still filter using the pipeline: `(qwinsta /server:$server | foreach { (($_.trim() -replace "\s+",","))} | ConvertFrom-Csv) | where {$_.UserName -match "xxx" -and $_.state -match "Ictive|Idle|Disconnected"}`

Comment: Ok i am sorry and thank you, is there a way how to filter this, get this information via the if statement not using this one with pipeline?

Comment: I would like to make conidtions for different users based on their session states…

Comment: Erase your second condition in your if statement, and just print out the state: `if ($queryResults.UserName -Match "xxx")` then in your body: `{ "xxx is $($queryResults.State)" }`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to look for both on the same line, although this doesn't take advantage of any properties:

```
if ($queryResults -match 'tnejtek|active') {
  write-host "tnejtek is connected"
}
else {
  'user not found'
}
```

Or (any result becomes true)

```
if ($queryResults | where {$_.username -eq 'tnejtek' -and $_.state -eq 'active') {
  write-host "tnejtek is connected"
}
else {
  'user not found'
}
```

Comment: @js2010 how do you mean any result become true?

Comment: Any non-empty result in a where or if statement is true, like 'hi' is true.

Comment: I am trying to define the allowed state in which user can be to be defined as "connected"

  $allowedstate = @("Active","Idle","Disc")

if ($queryResults | where {$_.username -eq 'tnejtek' -and $_.state -in $allowedstate) {
  write-host "tnejtek is connected"
}
else {
  'user not found'
}

but this does not work...do you know why?

Comment: It works for me.  You're missing a `}`.  You don't need `@()` to make an array, just the commas.  It's a myth.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you're looking to check for a specific user (defined previously) on the `qwinsta` result, and if the user is found and the state of the user is ***one of*** the states defined previously, display said user and it's details, else return a message saying that the user was not found.

```
# States should be the exact word to match
$validstates = 'Active', 'Idle', 'Disconnected'
$user = 'tnejtek'

qwinsta /server:$server | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() -replace "\s+","," } |
ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object {
    $_.Username -match $user -and $_.State -in $validstates
} | & {
    process
    {
        if(-not $_) { return "$user is not found!" }
        'ID: {0} - Username: {1} - State: {2}' -f $_.ID, $_.Username, $_.State
    }
}
```